# How to ignore a certain type of files when committing

Tags: git, gitignore

I have this Python Project in eclipse and in every run he creates these .pyc files. How can I make `git` ignore these files. I know how to ignore a certain file with `.gitignore` but is it possible to ignore all files with a certain extension?

Comment: Try adding `*.pyc` to the `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to ignore file with extensions `.pyc`, `.info` and `.ini`

add the following lines in your `.gitignore` file

```
*.pyc
*.info
*.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this** This is my .gitignore

---

```
# Compiled source #
###################
*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*.o
*.so

# Packages #
############
# it's better to unpack these files and commit the raw source
# git has its own built in compression methods
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip

# Logs and databases #
######################
*.log
*.sql
*.sqlite

# OS generated files #
######################
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db
```